# I Develop a project on "monodevelop" but stuck in debugging it from .exe file. What should I do?

Tags: application-development, archive, monodevelop

I have developed a project using **monodevelop** and saved it. The **monodevelop** as usual created a *.exe* file of it for me, But problem with the project is that,"It works perfect, When I start debugging it with in the development environment. And when I close monodevelop app and want to access it from .exe file it pops up a window, Which says (**Archive Manager** an error occurred while load the archive)". Now what should I install to erase this error.

Answer (score 4):

MonoDevelop is an IDE for making .NET applications that can run on anything with a .NET runtime. Your EXE can run on any Linux machine with Mono installed. The same file will also run on Windows (assuming you are using basic cross-platform practices). Applications like this are in the Portable Executable format, so they have the EXE extension that specifies this (Windows won't execute it otherwise).

"Mono" is the name of an implementation of the .NET runtime for Linux systems. Since you are already using MonoDevelop, I bet your system already has Mono installed and working. You can run it with mono by using a command that is something like this:

```
mono application.exe
```

P.S. - I've noticed that explicitly specifying mono isn't necessary on my most updated systems. I don't know the details, but I can now execute such apps even more simply. Like any other linux application:

```
./application.exe
```

Comment: I know this is an ancient thread. But wow... the existing answer is so uninformed.

Comment: Yeah, looking back at what I wrote back then, shortly after I signed up here, I must admit you're right. Unfortunately I can't delete my answer currently as it is marked accepted. The `.exe` file outputted is not a plain PE (Windows Portable Executable) but just a PE stub that launches the CLR (Common Language Runtime) which then executes the contained .NET assembly part. That's just a minor detail though, so have my upvote for correcting me :)